# IE 11 Overlapping issue in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form in which `bootstrap` css is applied and which works pretty well in almost every browser but when i run the same form in IE browser it breaks. The elements overlap withe each other.

See the snapshot below:

[image]

I have the following bootstrap CSS:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-4">
        Quote By IMEI
    </label>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <input name="files" type="file" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-4">
        Quote By MPX Model ID
    </label>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <input name="files" type="file" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-4">
        Quote By Model Names
    </label>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <input name="files" type="file" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**This code is working fine on every browser except IE. Can someone please help me let me know where i am wrong**

Comment: Please mention IE version.

Comment: @Karthikeyan please check updated title now

Comment: Looks bad in FireFox too. The file input changes from browser to browser so this type of layout won't work unless you use a plugin to make the file input consistent: http://www.abeautifulsite.net/whipping-file-inputs-into-shape-with-bootstrap-3/

Comment: Possible help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22302106/pages-does-not-render-properly-in-ie-11-when-using-the-bootsrapv3-0-0-theme