# Bootstrap tutorial example for dropdown nav menu not working in IE11

Tags: html, css

I have been playing around with the Bootstrap Dropdowns tutorial on the w3schools website.  The "Try it Yourself" buttons allow me to simulate the Dropdown right on their site.  And that works fine on IE11.  However, when I copy the source code to my own server and try to run it there, the drop-down doesn't do anything in IE11, although it works perfectly fine in Chrome and Firefox.

I assumed (apparently incorrectly) that I could just copy the HTML & CSS source code that apears on the TryIt page and it would be a self-contained working example.  And it does appear to be for both Chrome and Firefox.

Anybody have any idea what is missing to make it work in IE11?

Here is the URL I had been playing with on the w3schools site:

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_dropdown-menu&stacked=h

Comment: [Might be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22302106/pages-does-nt-render-properly-in-ie-11-when-using-the-bootsrapv3-0-0-theme)

Comment: Thank you Tico.  That link you included was very helpful.  It looks like I was able to fix my problem by adding this to the <head> section of my HTML document:  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

Comment: Nice. I've had some troubles -- still do, only IE11 -- but I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by adding this code to you `<head>` section:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

It's a well known problem, not just with `Bootstrap`.